# how to use Linq " NOT IN"

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm using Entity Framework
So I want to write a sql command using two tables - tblContractor and tbSiteByCont tables.
It looks like this in SQL

```
SELECT     PKConID, Fname, Lname
FROM         tblContractor
WHERE     (PKConID NOT IN
                          (SELECT     FKConID
                            FROM          tbSiteByCont
                            WHERE      (FKSiteID = 13)))
```

but I don't know how to write in Linq.

I tried like this

```
  var query1 = from s in db.tblSiteByConts   
                        where  s.FKSiteID == id
                        select s.FKConID;


            var query = from c in db.tblContractors   
                        where c.PKConID != query1.Any()
                        select Contractor;
```

But this doesn't work.
So how should I write it? What is the procedure? I'm new to Linq.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var _result = from a in tblContractor
              where !(from b in tbSiteByCont
                        where FKSiteID  == 13
                        select b.FKConID)
                        .Contains(a.PKConID)
              select a;
```

or

```
var siteLst = tbSiteByCont.Where(y => y.FKSiteID == 13)
                          .Select(x => x.FKConID);
var _result = tblContractor.Where(x => !siteLst.Contains(x.PKConID));
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a HashSet, it ensures you only evaluate the sequence once.

```
var result = from p in tblContractor
                      let hasht = new HashSet<int>((from b in tbSiteByCont
                                                    where b.FKSiteID == 13
                                                    select b.PKConID).Distinct())
                      where !hasht.Contains(p.PKConID)
                      select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

may this work too

```
var _result = from a in tblContractor
                       .Where(c => tbSiteByCont
                       .Count(sbc => sbc.FKSiteID == 13 && c.PKConID == sbc.FKConID) == 0)
```